# MongoDB Search for all values in array

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Given an array of values I need to search through a MongoDB collection and return the combined results without making multiple find calls to the database. I would like to make a single call to the database and get the combined results

This is what I currently do (not exactly but its similar):

```
searchArray = ["hi", "bye"]
for item in searchedArray:
    db.collection.find({"Field": item})
```

The problem with this is that I cannot combine the results that each `.find` call returned. This approach is also making several `.find` calls to the database(one for every elements in the searchedArray). I would like to make a single call and get all the combined results back.

Is there any way to do something like this but with every element of a given array and get all the combined results back:

```
searchedArray = ["hi", "bye"]
results = db.collection.find({"Field": 'hi'} and {"Field": 'bye'})
```

Comment: Do you wanted to get docs where both `["hi", "bye"]` exists ? or it is an `or` operation rather than `and` ?

Comment: @whoami i need it to be an `or` operation

Comment: ok then you can use `$in`..

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator. [Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zkBL37fGxsW)

```
db.collection.find( { field: { $in: [ 'hi' , 'value'] } } )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get documents which has all elements from input array then you need to use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/index.html) operator.

```
db.collection.find( { Field: { $all: [ 'hi' , 'bye'] } } ) // input array :: [ 'hi' , 'bye']
```

Above matches documents where field named `Field` has both values from passed in input array.

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j6g0rVK5v3t)

But if you wanted to get documents even if at least one element from input array matches, then you need to use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator.

```
db.collection.find( { Field: { $in: [ 'hi' , 'bye'] } } )
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KhhdUvutpHr)